# Finding a way to convert a set of variables in relation to another variable DBSCAN

Tags: design-patterns, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I'm looking for a way/method on how to convert a set of variables in relation to another variable so that I can use the values for the DBSCAN algorithm to work.

My set of variables is called "Interest" where one data can contain at least 3 out of 14 interests.
my data seems to have many unique sets of interest and when I try to convert it to numeric, the patterns within the "Interests" is destroyed thus destroying the cluster itself.

How can I convert the data (Interests) into numeric form where the pattern within the interests won't be destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN does not need numerical data.

You can use e.g. Jaccard index to measure set similarity.

Comment: assuming that I already have my numeric data, what then should I do to convert it to whatever DBSCAN needs?

Comment: DBSCAN needs a similarity function. One which you understand well enough to choose Epsilon. For example, I have geodata. Latitude and Longitude are numeric. For distance, I want to use great-circle distance, and the epsilon radius for my application is 10 miles. No need to "convert" anything (but you do need to understand "similarity" on your data!).